# Heroku - Find Node.js extension version intalled

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, pg

I have a node.js running on heroku. I'm using some dependecies for node.js and I needed to know which version of pg node.js extension npm has installed.

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name":        "myapp",
  "version":     "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "0.4.3",
    "express": "2.4.6",
    "socket.io": "0.8.4",
    "pg": ">=0.0.1" 
  }
}
```

The problem is that there's a new feature in pg that I wanted to use and I'm not sure if the latest version is being built.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to specify the last version instead of ">=0.0.1" (ex. "pg": "0.6.6"), that way you'll be sure the latest version gets installed.